# Print a text-trapezoid in C

Tags: c

Hey guys I am struggling with my program. It should print a trapezoid like this:

```
ccc
cccc
ccccc
cccccc
```

This is what I came up with:

```
int main() {
    int n, m, row, column;
    char c;
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c", & c);

    printf("Enter number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d", & n);

    printf("Enter number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d", & m);

    for (row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
        for (column = 1; column <= m; column++) {
            printf("%c", c);
        }
        printf("\n");


    }
    return 0;

}
```

Parameters `c = c`, `n = 4`, `m = 3` prints:

```
ccc
ccc
ccc
ccc
```

Comment: You've got the right number of rows. But how many columns should each row have? You need to use pencil and paper to find the mathematical formula for the number of columns, before you can even begin coding.

Comment: Did you run this inside a debugger?

Comment: `printf("\n");` --> `printf("\n");m++;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never change the width of each row. Try incrementing `m`, like this:

```
int main(){
    int n,m,row,column;
    char c;
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c",&c);

    printf("Enter number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);

    for ( row = 1 ; row <= n ; row++ )
    {
        for( column = 1 ; column <= m ; column++ ){
            printf("%c",c);
        }
        printf("\n");
        m++; // this is the missing component!
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output (with the settings you specified, `c = 'c', n = 4, m = 3`):

```
ccc
cccc
ccccc
cccccc
```

Comment: Thanks alot Ed Cottrell